# Trouble loading azure-cosmos library for Python 3.8 Azure Function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm having a challenging time getting the Python azure-cosmos library to correctly load for the purposes of locally testing a function in VS Code.

The specific error I'm getting (with the file path shortened) is: `Exception: ImportError: cannot import name 'exceptions' from 'azure.cosmos' ([shortened]/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/cosmos/__init__.py)`

Things I've checked/tried so far:

- Check that requirements.txt specifies azure-cosmos
- Manually go into python for each of the interpreters available within VS code and ensure I can manually import azure.cosmos
- As instructed [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-python-getting-started), attempt to reinstall the azure-cosmos library using `pip3` and ensuring the `--pre` flag is used.
- **[Updated]** Verified I can successfully `import azure.cosmos.cosmos_client as cosmos_client` without any errors

Any ideas? Thanks! Below is the relevant section of my code.

```
import datetime
import logging
import tempfile
import requests
import os
import zipfile
import pandas as pd
import azure.functions as func
from azure.cosmos import exceptions, CosmosClient, PartitionKey

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest, calendars: func.Out[func.Document]) -> None:
    logging.info("Timer function has initiated.")
```

Comment: So you are not using the azure function cosmos binding?

Comment: @GeorgeChen Yes, actually, I intend to eventually. Once I implement that, does this library become unnecessary? (Sorry for the basic question; still new to Azure.)  Even still, I'd expect the library to be able to load given that it loads everywhere else.

Comment: On my side, it is no problem. It works well. Actually, Azure Function SDK contains some necessary packages. What the Python 3.8 you are using? 64bit or 32 bit? Can you show your code?

Comment: @BowmanZhu I'm using Python 3.8.0 64-bit.

Comment: Hi, I think the root reason is the version of the packages. But only run install pre will not solve. You need to delete all of the related packages first, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Hi, i have post an answer, can you work now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you face now:

[image]

This is the offcial doc:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-python-getting-started

This doc tells you how to solve this problem.

So the solution is to install pre version.(George Chen's solution is right.)

Didn't install the pre version is the root reason, but please notice that, you need to first delete the package. Otherwise, the pre version will not be installed.(Only run install pre will not solve this problem, you need to delete all of the related packages first. And then install the pre package.)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I made it work after removing and reinstalling just the azure-cosmos package. You mentioned "all of the related packages"--is there another one I should remove and reinstall as well?

Comment: @George In my case, the cosmos installation of the pre version will still be blocked if only the cosmos package is deleted, so I deleted all the azure related packages and then reinstalled without problems. If you just delete the cosmos package and it works, then do n’t delete it all. just make it work is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Whether azure.cosmos is needed depends on whether function binding meets your needs, if the binding could do what you want suppose you don't need to use `azure.cosmos`.

About this import error, I could reproduce this exception, and I check the github solution it have to add a `--pre` flag.

So my solution is go to `task.json` under `.vscde`, add the flag to the command like below.

[image]

If you want to get more details about cosmos binding you could refer to this doc:[Azure Cosmos DB trigger and bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2)

Comment: Thank you, but still no luck. I added --pre, and I also tried using pip3, which I have to use in Terminal outside of VSCode. Still receiving the same error. In fact, when I switch to pip3, I get "No module named pip3"